# zebra table with ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm adding record to table with ajax button. I want to use zebra table.
I have a jquery function for zebra table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("table tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("zebraTable");
        });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.zebraTable {background-color: #F2F2F2}
```

When I call on click of normal button, it works like zebra table. but when I change button with ajax button, table turns normal table.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can provide for the button and the table source?

Comment: You don't need javascript anymore to do that kind of table. You should directly put it in your css http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what has happened to the table since you added the zebraTable class to the rows.  I'm assuming your Ajax call is modifying the table (replacing it, adding/removing rows, hiding/showing rows, etc.)?

Just be aware that the tr objects in your DOM will retain that class unless you remove it and that the selector is applied to both hidden and visible tr objects.  My suggestion would be to remove the zebraTable class from all rows and then re-apply it (and adjust for hidden tr objects if you have them).

Comment: I just changed button type. I have used ajax button instead of button and then zebra table didn't work.

Comment: Ah, I figured you meant a button that does Ajax.  Sounds like Ajax button is from a third-party library or maybe my Google skills are lacking.  At any rate, use a developer toolbar (IE/Firefox/Google all have something like this) to review the before/after state of the table.  This should help you determine what you need to do once the button is clicked.  My thought is that the button is changing the DOM elements (preserving css styling) while the Ajax button is adding/removing DOM elements (losing css styling).